# Oracle two query in a script? Is it possible?

Tags: oracle

For example i want to run this on oracle is it possible?

```
ACCEPT num PROMPT 'enter num: ' SELECT a.tbl1 FROM tbl1 a, tbl2 b WHERE a.id
= b.id AND a.num = '&num';
```

If there is result, proceed with second query

```
DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE num = '&num';
```

Is it possible to run 2 query in a script? Sorry i am new in Oracle.

Looking to do this in SQLPLUS

Comment: Yes its possible - but you've not provided any information about how you expect to implement this - sql*plus? Something else?

Comment: yes, sqlplus, sorry for not mentioning earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL as presented can easily be compressed into a single DELETE statement.  This is because a DELETE statement won't hurl an exception when doesn't find any rows to delete.

Given this test data:

```
SQL> select * from tbl1
  2  /

        ID        NUM
---------- ----------
        10        999
        20        999
        10        888

SQL> select * from tbl2
  2  /

        ID
----------
        10


SQL>
```

We pass in the same value twice; the first time a record will get deleted, the next time nothing happens but gracefully....

```
SQL> DELETE FROM tbl1 a
  2  WHERE a.num = '&num'
  3  and exists (select b.id
  4              from tbl2 b
  5              WHERE a.id = b.id )
  6  /
Enter value for num: 999
old   2: WHERE a.num = '&num'
new   2: WHERE a.num = '999'

1 row deleted.

SQL> /
Enter value for num: 999
old   2: WHERE a.num = '&num'
new   2: WHERE a.num = '999'

0 rows deleted.

SQL>
```

---

Of course, you may have presented a simplified case here, and your real needs are more complicated.  If so, please edit you question to reflect something more realistic.